# Where to catch exception in WebClient method?

Tags: json, windows-phone-7, webclient

I'm developing app which connects to service and consume some JSON data. Consuming works great (JSON.net rocks) but I wonder where I should catch exception error annd show simple MessageBox? Tried in few places but still my app is closing. Or maybe I should do it based on json response which contain error tag? I think that normal error handling could be easier, but have blank spot in my mind now..

Code is below:

```
private void LoginLoginButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            ((ApplicationBarIconButton)ApplicationBar.Buttons[0]).IsEnabled = false;
            ProgressOverlay.Show();
            GenerateLoginString();
            var w = new SharpGIS.GZipWebClient();

            Observable.FromEvent<DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs>(w, "DownloadStringCompleted")
              .Subscribe(r =>
              {

                  var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;


                  var deserializedRootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(r.EventArgs.Result);

                  UserSettings us = new UserSettings()
                  {


                          first_name = deserializedRootObject.user.first_name,
                          last_name = deserializedRootObject.user.last_name,
                          user_id = deserializedRootObject.user_id,

                    };
                    settings.Add("UserSettings", us);
                    settings.Save();
              });
            w.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(UserUri));
            w.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(w_DownloadStringCompleted);

        }

        void w_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to catch an exception which occurs in your web client call then it should be in the `Error` property of `DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs`.

```
void w_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Error != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("An error occurred!");
    }
    else
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this one. But the error appears again. And it appears in the moment when UserSettings object can not be filled. The scenario is: if login data is okay, I get object call UserSettings, if no I get only one json entry called error: "error"

Comment: So I guess I should try to catch exception in place when I know what result I am gonna get

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

I used try and catch in this case. Works perfect :)